# How to enable delete button on android table row view when left-to-right swipe?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have tableview on android app. I need to enable delete button when we swipe from left-to-right or right-to-left on table row and need to disable button when we click anywhere on screen. It should work from 2.3 to jellybean. Please provide me solution for this.

Answer (score 4):

Such option is called FLING in android...

Check is sample:
https://github.com/krishjlk/android-listview-swipe-delete-example-sample-tuorial

May help

EDIT :

```
private class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        System.out.println("UFFFFF");
        if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            System.out.println("Right to left");

            return false; // Right to left
        } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            System.out.println("Left to right");
            iv5.setBackgroundDrawable(enterShape);
            Intent go=new Intent(Swipe.this,NewContact.class);
            startActivity(go);
            return false; // Left to right
        }

        if (e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            return false; // Bottom to top
        } else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            return false; // Top to bottom
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Exceptional, but code does not consists of any swipe functionality. It just showing list view.